# ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm currently trying to scrape this https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000109072720000003/form8-kq42019earningsr.htm SEC link with beautifulsoup to get the link containing "UPS"

```
pressting = soup3.find_all("a", string="UPS")
linkkm = pressting.get('href')
print(linkkm)
```

But when I do this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\SEC.py", line 55, in <module>
    print('Price: ' + str(edgar()))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\SEC.py", line 46, in edgar
    linkkm = pressting.get('href')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2081, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

My expected result is to exract the href and then print that href. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: am not sure which `href` you are expecting to get?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I'm trying to get the href of this line:  99.1       Press release dated January 30, 2020 "UPS RELEASES 4Q 2019 EARNINGS" . Which is https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000109072720000003/exhibit991-q42019earni.htm

Comment: check below answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the page is dynamically rendered via `JavaScript` once it's loads. so you will not be able to parse the objects until you render it firstly. Therefore `requests` module will not render the `JavaScript`.

You can use `selenium` approach to achieve that. otherwise you can use `HTMLSession` from `html_request` module to render it on the fly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000109072720000003/form8-kq42019earningsr.htm")

sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("a", style=re.compile("^text")):
    print(item.get("href"))

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000109072720000003/exhibit991-q42019earni.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000109072720000003/exhibit992-q42019finan.htm
```

However if you want just the first url;

```py
url = soup.find("a", style=re.compile("^text")).get("href")
print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000109072720000003/exhibit991-q42019earni.htm
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer is there a possibility of improving the speed?

Comment: @DaRealHeroofHell that question is based on your environment and where you are running the code. you can use `requests_html` module. are you going to parse multiple urls ?

Comment: @DaRealHeroofHell `from requests_html import HTMLSession` will be good for you to go with

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that soup3.find_all() returns a list of results and you are trying to use the .get() method on this list, when you are supposed to use it on only one item.

Try something like iterating through them and printing each one:

```
pressting = soup3.find_all("a", string="UPS")
for i in pressting:
    print(i.get('href'))
```

Comment: Hi this doesn't work either. This is the error it gives me:

Comment: @DaRealHeroofHell I edited my answer, give that a try.

Comment: That doesn't return anything