# Tag Search with BeautifulSoup Failing with Java-Generated HTML

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to capture urls in a page of html.  The page requires an asyncronis call to fully generate the embedded urls.  For some reason, BeautifulSoup isn't picking up the tags.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
link = "https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000008/a8-kq1202012282019.htm"
driver.get(link)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.findall('a'))
```

The relevant section of `soup` is as follows when viewed:

```
         <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-left:2px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;">
           <div style="font-size:9pt;">
            <a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000008/a8-kexhibit991q1202012.htm" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#0000FF;-sec-extract:exhibit;" tabindex="18">
             <span style="font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">
              Press release issued by Apple Inc. on January 28, 2020.
             </span>
```

I'm trying to get the `a href`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: html = self.driver.page_source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587529/resultset-object-has-no-attribute-get)

Comment: How do you want to find that one particular link out of all the other links on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000008/a8-kq1202012282019.htm")

sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("a", style=re.compile("^text")):
    print(item.get("href"))

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000008/a8-kexhibit991q1202012.htm
```

Comment: Thanks.  What do the 'options' do?  Also, i dont see how Selenium is running the javascript is it happening when 'driver.get()' is called?

Comment: the `headless` option will running the browser without a graphical user interface. This program will behave just like a browser but will not show any GUI.

Comment: Does selenium automatically run the javascript when driver.get() runs?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 yes it's act the same as you are browsing manually, which means it's open the url and the `JavaScript` got rendered.

Comment: One more thing:  could you explain what the `style=re.compile("^text")` does?

Comment: [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is `Regular expression operations` where we are compiling any `anchor` tag including style `startswith` word `text`